# How to resize an animated png with ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick, png

I want to resize a animated png with ImageMagick.
I tried command like this:

```
convert animation.png -coalesce -resize 500x500 -layers optimize -loop 0 resize.png
```

However, it only works on GIF but not on apng.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Animated PNG is in APNG format, then you would need to do the following in Imagemagick 7. Not sure it works in the older Imagemagick 6.

```
magick APNG:animation.png -coalesce -resize 500x500 -layers optimize -loop 0 APNG:new_animation.png
```

This is untested. I am not sure if -layers optimize works on APNG.

Comment: Thank you, this command works but the file size of the image outputted is huge, like 10x larger

Comment: You could try adding -quality for PNG. See https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality